# Git bash on Windows - sftp not supported

Tags: git, bash, sftp, msysgit

I would like to use GIT Bash to upload files on server. I am using msysgit for Windows.

FTP upload is ok, but sftp not working.

`git ftp init --verbose`

gives me error: **sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl**

I was trying to install libssh2 to Cygwin with this reference http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC150

But error still ocured. I don't know if I must install something directly to GIT Bash or what can I do else?

Thank you for any advices.

---

Edit: I updated msysgit and other software, now I just don't know how to get certificate from the server. From WinSCP I use only accept fingerprint and that was it.

`curl -v --insecure sftp://user:password@xxx.com`

- SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
- Using SSH public key file '(nil)'
- Using SSH private key file 'C:\Users\xxx/.ssh/id_rsa'
- SSH public key authentication failed: Username/PublicKey combination invalid

curl: (67) Authentication failure

I saw here https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/124 that I can use another key instead of my default. But I don't know how to get that key from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are not using git with Cygwin or the [old and obsolete msysgit 1.9.x version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309).

With the [new git for windows,](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) `sftp` should be supported:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\seec>c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\usr\bin\curl.exe -V
curl 7.44.0 (x86_64-pc-msys) libcurl/7.44.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2d zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 libssh2/1.6.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets Metalink
```

> This project which needs sftp requires only user and password without any certificate file

True, no need for an [ssl certificate with sftp](https://superuser.com/a/561783/141), simply make there is no key in '`C:\Users\xxx/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`'

> From WinSCP I use only accept fingerprint and that was it.

That could be the issue: the `known_host` must have the remote server fingerprint. See [for instance my script](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/679c9453058c7d8fcf1cf2ee4dc40e7a7746c17a/sshd/post_install_ssh.sh#L38-L46) or this blog post:

> To get a look at the server’s public key fingerprint before attempting a connection, one can utilize the `ssh-keyscan` program

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa host.example.org > tmp
ssh-keygen -lf tmp 
256 03:ed:6d:1f:ff:56:9d:5f:f3:65:20:b5:ad:55:55:87 host.example.org (ECDSA)
```

> Here the `-t` is for type of key to be scanned (which can be rsa1 for protocol version 1, dsa, ecdsa, ed25519, or rsa for protocol version 2).
>   The output is redirected to a temporary file named `tmp`, then the file is checked with the `ssh-keygen` program.
>
> Once client has verified the fingerprint, it will store a copy of the server’s public key in `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` and will check the stored key on subsequent connections to that host.
>   If the server has changed its keys, or another machine is attempting to spoof the real server, the client will notice and will not allow connections to that host.

Comment: @ManicDepression a bit like https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/208, I suppose? Check what `curl -v --insecure sftp://ftp.xxx.com:22/var/www/xxx.com` return. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31750959/6309

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of the curl -v command? Just in case I see something? Check if the environment variable HOME is defined.

Comment: @ManicDepression seems clear: try moving away (not deleting, just moving) the `id_rsa(.pub)` ssh key files from `C:\Users\xxx\.ssh`, just to see if the `user:password` works.

Comment: ok let's try the opposite: move back your ssh keys, but do not input username and password

Comment: @ManicDepression OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Official GitHub link for the [Issue](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/91).

[cURL for Windows](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/)

Procedure to [Add Sftp-capabilities to cURL](http://iamnearlythere.com/add-sftp-capabilities-to-curl/) in Linux(Ubuntu)