# Update SSH key/RSA fingerprint for GitHub (Ubuntu-20.04) not working

Tags: github, ssh, ubuntu-20.04, rsa-key-fingerprint, known-hosts

My GitHub ssh key is expired. I tried to update it, which works on GitHub's site, but my laptop just shows me the old RSA fingerprint when I try to push/pull/clone. So currently,
my laptop has no access to GitHub now.

*There a similar questions on StackOverflow (but they are not covering my case):*

- *[How can I force ssh to accept a new host fingerprint from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383806/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-accept-a-new-host-fingerprint-from-the-command-line)*
- *[How to generate ssh keys (for github)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828823/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-github)*
- *[git clone through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167905/git-clone-through-ssh)*

**When I try to push/pull, following **message** appears**

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.

> RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xyz/0GFYZ+xPpuxU.

> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

Hitting `yes` results in having no access, because the fingerprint mentioned in the message is expired. Entering a new `fingerprint` seems not to work, because the message just appears again.

For sure, I tried to update the ssh key. **Undertaken steps**:

1. deleted the old ssh key on GitHub (Settings --> SSH and GPG keys --> [Ðelete] old key)
2. created a new ssh key in my terminal with `ssh-keygen -o`
3. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` were updated
4. got my fingerprint, let's say `SHA265:abcdefg name@name-P452USF`
5. saved the ssh key on GitHub.
6. **message appears again** after trying to pull/clone/push. Again the **message** shows the expired fingerprint
7. deleted content of `~/.ssh/known_host`, because the expired fingerprint is stored here.
8. repeated steps 1-5
9. **message occurs again** (why/where is expired fingerprint still stored???)

Rebooting my device does not work too.

Entering the new fingerprint does not work (why?). After hitting `[Enter]` the message appears again.

Comment: In the `~/.ssh/config` file you should be able to see which rsa id is actually used by Github. It should indeed be `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but is it really?

Comment: I have no file `~/.ssh/config`. Also, there is no hidden file like this.

Answer (score 1):

> deleted content of `~/.ssh/known_host`, because the expired fingerprint is stored here.

This should usually work (though on my computer the filename is `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with an `s`).

However, per the [SSH man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) there is also a system-wide config file with known host keys:

> ```
>  /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
>         Systemwide list of known host keys.  This file should be prepared by the system
>         administrator to contain the public host keys of all machines in the organization.
>         It should be world-readable.  See sshd(8) for further details of the format of this
>         file.
> ```

If you remove the expired fingerprint from that file as well, does it work?

This command should remove just that fingerprint without affecting other known hosts in the file:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -f "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts" -R github.com
```